# Get attribute value from ng-click $event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have an anchor that has a **bold** text and a **ng-click** event for angular. In controller, i want to get the property **href** but i got a problem. It will work if i will not put a **bold** tag inside anchor since the event.target will target directory to anchor but if i put a **bold** tag on the text, it (*event.target*) will not target to anchor but will target to **bold** tag

I tried this but still the result is **undefined**

```
<div ng-app="miniapp">
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
        <a  ng-click="clickEvent($event)" 
            href="http://google.com"><b>Click Me</b></a>
    </div>
</div>

var app = angular.module('miniapp', []);

function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.clickEvent = function(obj) {
        obj.preventDefault();        

        var target = angular.element(obj.target);
        alert(target.attr('href'));
    }
};
```

[Click Here for fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vgdagpin/FAeJq/213/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

`obj.target`

Use:

`obj.currentTarget`

Current target is the element the event listener is created on, target is the element that triggered the event.